# postgresql: dump database with symbolic references?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, symbols, dump, relation

Foreign keys define the relation between database tables. Is there any tool in order to dump/export the database (postgresql) by using a relation instead of the id. The dump should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.speciesconfignumericvalues(speciesid, topicid, numericvalue)
VALUES ((select speciesid from public.species where speciesname = 'rollershutter'),(select topicid 
FROM public.topics where topicname = 'wind_speed_limit'),30);
```

Instead I get:

```
INSERT INTO public.speciesconfignumericvalues(speciesid, topicid, numericvalue)
VALUES (12,345,30);
```

Is it possible to get a dump like the first example, e.g. by defining foreign keys? 
Reason: I have two databases with same species, topics etc. but different id for the same. So I cannot easily insert data from one database into the other without programming a specific application for this.